# Laratrust show user role inside of team

Tags: laravel, laravel-7, eloquent-relationship, laratrust

I am trying to make a connection between teams and users.
Pretty much Latrust looks like an awesome package **BUT** some things I believe could be explained better.

Let's pick a team (say: team_id = 1):
`$team = Team::where('id', $request->team_id)->first();`

And let's pick our users from the team:

```
$roles = Role::get();
$users = User::whereRoleIs($roles->pluck('name')->toArray(), $team)->get()
```

This will result in the following:

```
{
    "message": "ok",
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "niki",
            "email": "niki@user.com",
            "email_verified_at": null,
            "created_at": "2021-07-12T11:29:09.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2021-07-12T11:29:09.000000Z",
            "roles": [
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "name": "user",
                    "display_name": "User",
                    "description": "User",
                    "created_at": "2021-07-12T11:29:08.000000Z",
                    "updated_at": "2021-07-12T11:29:08.000000Z",
                    "pivot": {
                        "user_id": 1,
                        "role_id": 3,
                        "user_type": "App\\Models\\User"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "id": 4,
                    "name": "leader",
                    "display_name": "Leader",
                    "description": "Leader",
                    "created_at": "2021-07-12T11:29:08.000000Z",
                    "updated_at": "2021-07-12T11:29:08.000000Z",
                    "pivot": {
                        "user_id": 1,
                        "role_id": 4,
                        "user_type": "App\\Models\\User"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "konna",
            "email": "konna@user.com",
            "email_verified_at": null,
            "created_at": "2021-07-12T11:29:09.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2021-07-12T11:29:09.000000Z",
            "roles": [
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "name": "user",
                    "display_name": "User",
                    "description": "User",
                    "created_at": "2021-07-12T11:29:08.000000Z",
                    "updated_at": "2021-07-12T11:29:08.000000Z",
                    "pivot": {
                        "user_id": 2,
                        "role_id": 3,
                        "user_type": "App\\Models\\User"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "name": "user",
                    "display_name": "User",
                    "description": "User",
                    "created_at": "2021-07-12T11:29:08.000000Z",
                    "updated_at": "2021-07-12T11:29:08.000000Z",
                    "pivot": {
                        "user_id": 2,
                        "role_id": 3,
                        "user_type": "App\\Models\\User"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

This returns **all the roles those two users have (both of them belong in the same team)**

How can we pick **ONLY** the role that the user has inside the team?

I thought of the following:
Getting all the user records with the `$users` query and then picking the role of the user from there.

```
 foreach ($users as $user){
        $userArray[] = array_push($userArray, $user->name, $user->roles->first());
    }
```

However, this will return the first() or last() role attached to the user which can be anything (especially when a user may belong to multiple teams with a different role attached to every team he attends).

So my question is, how can I show the role of a user inside a team?

I was thinking of:

```
$user->roles->where($team->id)
```

But this returns all the roles that are attached to the user and not the specific role that the user has on the team.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @mrhn for your valuable input

My solution came in the following form:

```
$rolesInTeam[] = null;
$users = User::whereRoleIs($roles->pluck('name')->toArray(), $team)->get();

foreach ($users as $user){
$rolesInTeam[] = array_push($rolesInTeam,$user->roles()->wherePivotIn(Config::get('laratrust.foreign_keys.team'), $team)->get());
}
```

Which returns as a result:

````
    null,
    [
        {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "leader",
            "display_name": "Leader",
            "description": "Leader",
            "created_at": "2021-07-12T11:29:08.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2021-07-12T11:29:08.000000Z",
            "pivot": {
                "user_id": 1,
                "role_id": 4,
                "user_type": "App\\Models\\User"
            }
        }
    ],
    2,
    [
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "user",
            "display_name": "User",
            "description": "User",
            "created_at": "2021-07-12T11:29:08.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2021-07-12T11:29:08.000000Z",
            "pivot": {
                "user_id": 2,
                "role_id": 3,
                "user_type": "App\\Models\\User"
            }
        }
    ],
    4,
    [
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "user",
            "display_name": "User",
            "description": "User",
            "created_at": "2021-07-12T11:29:08.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2021-07-12T11:29:08.000000Z",
            "pivot": {
                "user_id": 5,
                "role_id": 3,
                "user_type": "App\\Models\\User"
            }
        }
    ],
    6```
````

Answer (score 1):

I'm not experienced in Laratrust, but i feel like i have the solution you are needing. If we explode the [source code](https://github.com/santigarcor/laratrust/blob/47e343d392a15d12a9b5e0155321cc0d36d970ff/src/Traits/LaratrustUserTrait.php#L53), we can see your `UserTrait` includes a Role relationship. Even more so, we can see that it includes the pivot for the `Team` model.

```
if (Config::get('laratrust.teams.enabled')) {
    $roles->withPivot(Config::get('laratrust.foreign_keys.team'));
}
```

Combining that with the method `wherePivot()` that `Laravel` has, you would be able to do the following retrieving the user roles for a given team. Therefor you will retrieve all the roles if you use the condition, with the way `Laratrust` works, you can have multiple roles thou.

```
$rolesInTeam = $user->roles()->wherePivot(Config::get('laratrust.foreign_keys.team'), $team)->get();
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. I will try this out and let you know if it works